# Adding the values of same keys in one dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I have a Dictionary :

```
Dict1= {“AAT”: 2, “CCG”: 1, “ATA”: 5, “GCG”: 7, “CGC”: 2, “TAG”: 1, “GAT”: 0, “AAT”: 3, “CCG”: 2, “ATG”: 5, “GCG”: 3, “CGC”: 7, “TAG”: 0, “GAT”: 0}
```

And I have to sum all the similar triplet codes in a new dictionary.

Output should be like this:

```
Dict2 = {“AAT”: 5, “CCG”: 3, “ATA”: 5, “GCG”: 10, “CGC”: 9, “TAG”: 1, “GAT”: 0}
```

How do I proceed with the code?

Answer (score 1):

`Dict1` is not a valid dictionary as dictionary keys [have to be unique](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). In general if you have some (non-unique) strings and values assigned to them, you can write

```py
if key in Dict2:
    Dict2[key] += val
else
    Dict2[key] = val
```

Comment: I did this but I am getting an error - key is not defined

Comment: You have to define `key` and `val` yourself in some way as this is the code for a general case.

Comment: Alright, yes I am understand what you are hinting at. Thanks !

Comment: But then I will not be able to get it as the same output as above in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to sum up the values of same **keys** which not possible since python doesn't allow duplicate keys in dictionary. You can check this for reference:
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp